# Haskell "No instance for" error

Tags: haskell

I am trying to write a function that checks if a number is prime. I wrote this :

```
primeCheck :: Int -> Int -> Bool
primeCheck n i 
    | n == 2 = True
    | i == 1 = True
    | n `mod` i == 0 = False
    | otherwise = primeCheck n (i -1)

isPrime :: Int -> Bool
isPrime n = primeCheck n (floor (sqrt n))
```

And I get these errors :

> No instance for (RealFrac Int)
>         arising from a use of `floor'
>       Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (RealFrac Int)
>       In the second argument of`primeCheck', namely `(floor (sqrt n))'
>       In the expression: primeCheck n (floor (sqrt n))
>       In an equation for`isPrime':
>           isPrime n = primeCheck n (floor (sqrt n))
>
> ```
> No instance for (Floating Int)
>   arising from a use of `sqrt'
> Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Floating Int)
> In the first argument of `floor', namely `(sqrt n)'
> In the second argument of `primeCheck', namely `(floor (sqrt n))'
> In the expression: primeCheck n (floor (sqrt n)) Failed, modules loaded: none.
> ```

When I change the code to this to hopefully fix the problem:

```
primeCheck :: Int -> Int -> Bool
primeCheck n i 
    | n == 2 = True
    | i == 1 = True
    | n `mod` i == 0 = False
    | otherwise = primeCheck n (i -1)

isPrime :: Int -> Bool
isPrime n = primeCheck n (floor (RealFrac (sqrt  (Floating n))))
```

I get this :

> Not in scope: data constructor `RealFrac'
>
> Not in scope: data constructor `Floating'

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Floating` is a *typeclass*, not a constructor or function. You do seem to have figured out that you need to convert the type of `n`. The correct way to do this would be using `fromIntegral`:

```
isPrime n = primeCheck n $ floor $ sqrt $ (fromIntegral n :: Double)
```

We can see why this works by following the type signatures of the functions.

From the type signature of `isPrime`, we see `n` has type `Int`.

Since `sqrt` expects some `Floating` type (i.e. a type that is an instance of the typeclass `Floating`), we can convert from an `Int` to a `Double` using `fromIntegral`. Note that the signature of `fromIntegral` is

```
(Integral a, Num b) => a -> b
```

`Int` is an instance of `Integral` (so the input type is okay) and `Double` is an instance of `Num` so the output type is okay.

Then we take the `sqrt` to get a new `Double`.

`floor` expects an argument whose type is an instance of `RealFrac`. `Double` happens to be an instance of both `Floating` *and* `RealFrac`, so it will do the job (no conversion necessary). 
`floor` will convert the square root back to type `Int`.

Note that since the output type of `fromIntegral` is polymorphic, as is the input type of `sqrt` and `floor`, we have to specify the type of the conversion as `Double`, otherwise the compiler won't know *which* `Num`/`Floating`/`RealFrac` instance to convert to. You might see the error `ambiguous type 'a' in ...`.

You can see the type signatures of many functions using [Hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/)

**EDIT**

It turns out the explicit type signature for the `fromIntegral` is *not* required. Thus

```
isPrime n = primeCheck n $ floor $ sqrt $ fromIntegral n
```

suffices. In my opinion, it would be clearer to just provide the explicit signature, but it is not necessary in this case. You can read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21943624/why-is-an-explicit-type-not-required-for-basic-prelude-arithmetic).

Comment: Actually, after testing in both GHCi and GHC, I've found that the explicit type signature of the cast is *not* required, though I don't know why (especially for GHC, because GHCi has some funny defaulting rules).

Comment: GHC has almost all of the defaulting rules too; GHCi just has slightly relaxed conditions under which it will default types and will default some things to `()`. See http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.6.3/html/users_guide/interactive-evaluation.html#extended-default-rules You just notice it more in GHCi because compiling one line at a time means GHCi can't use the whole module to infer the correct type, and so defaulting rather than type inference picks your types more often.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in converting from the Int for use in sqrt. Change the last line to

```
isPrime n = primeCheck n (floor (sqrt (fromIntegral n)))
```

Answer (score 2):

`Floating` and `RealFrac` are type-classes, not functions.

This page gives a good overview of the standard Haskell numeric type-class hierarchy (section 6.3):

http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/basic.html

In particular, this diagram of the type-classes is very helpful:

http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/classes.gif

You clearly want to take the square root of an `Int` by using the floating point `sqrt` and `floor` functions. The problem is that these functions have the following types:

```
sqrt :: Floating a => a -> a
floor :: (Integral b, RealFrac a) => a -> b
```

The obstacles are:

1. `sqrt` takes a `Floating` argument, and `Int` is not in the `Floating` type class
2. `floor` requires a `RealFrac` argument, but `sqrt` produces only a `Floating`

You can solve the first with the `fromIntegral` function:

```
fromIntegral :: (Integral a, Num b) => a -> b
```

which will allow you to convert an `Int` (or any other integral type) into any `Num` type (which includes `Floating`.)

Next, looking at the chart of the numeric type-class hierarchy we see that `Double` and `Float` are members of both the `Floating` and `RealFrac` type-classes.

So by an explicit type coercion to `Double` you can apply `floor`:

```
isqrt :: Int -> Int
isqrt n = floor (sqrt (fromIntegral n) :: Double)
```

Now, as @lthread mentioned, you can get away with:

```
isqrt :: Int -> Int
isqrt n = (floor . sqrt . fromIntegral) n
```

and GHC will default the return type of `sqrt` to `Double`. It's perfectly fine to do this, but you should be aware that it is happening. For example, if you want to use this approach to take the integer square-root of an `Integer`, you want to pass through an abritrary precision real type (like a `Data.Number.BigFloat`) instead of a `Double`.