# Why is an explicit type NOT required for basic Prelude arithmetic?

Tags: haskell, ghc

I was [answering a question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21943252/925978) and wrote some code to get the job done.

```
isPrime :: Int -> Bool
isPrime n = primeCheck n $ floor $ sqrt $ (fromIntegral n :: Double)
```

I assumed that the explicit type signature would be required, as explained in my answer. Then I checked it in both GHC and GHCi and discovered that I did *not* need the explicit type for the conversion despite `floor` and `sqrt` being polymorphic. I know [GHCi does does some type defaulting](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.0.1/html/users_guide/interactive-evaluation.html), but I'm not aware of any in GHC. Obviously both `Float` and `Double` would be valid choices here, why does GHC choose one over the other? What type is defaulted to, and why does (presumably) GHC default in this case?

Comment: I had exactly the same question!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

GHC does type type-defaulting as well, at least whenever you export a module it will monomorphize any ambiguous numeric types to the types in `default` types for the module, which is by defaulted to:

```
default (Integer, Double)
```

See the section "4.3.4 Ambiguous Types, and Defaults for Overloaded Numeric Operations" in the [Haskell specification](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch4.html#x10-750004.3).

You can disable this with the pragma `{-# LANGUAGE NoMonomorphismRestriction #-}` in the  module you want to export with **toplevel** numeric polymorphic types left intact.

Comment: I tried using `NoMonomorphismRestriction` but still got defaulting in `isPrime`.

Comment: Are you asking how to disable defaulting everywhere in the module?

Comment: I'm asking if there is a way to disable the type defaulting for `isPrime`. I tried adding it to the main file, and also tried exporting `isPrime` with the language pragma in both modules, but type defaulting still occurs.

Comment: Write an explicitly polymorphic signature for the function:

``isPrime :: (Integral a, Num a) => a -> Bool``

Comment: That didn't work, nor would I expect it to: the type conversion happens *inside* `isPrime` and is "invisible" to the type signature/external interaction with the function.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking, you want a polymorphic function but you want to explicitly control the type of an internal computation instead of letting GHC deduce it? There's a couple ways to do that but I'm not I understand the motivation behind it, could you give me some context?

Comment: Not really any motivation, I just thought you were saying it was possible. But I think I see what you meant now.

Comment: One motivation to disable type defaulting would be for didactic purposes. It's hard to come up with a simpler example of where an explicit type signature would, under normal circumstances, be required.

Comment: It's possible but not simply, you'd have to pass in a specific type witness via an ``undefined`` and enable ScopedTypeVariables and other unpleasantness. I just can't think of an example where GHC would infer the wrong type it should always work, which is why I ask.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the `default` keyword?

It allows you to specify what to use when no signature is given. There is also a "default" default, which is `Double`.

I forget exactly how all of this works; it's a rather obscure corner of the language...

Comment: So that means it's actually Haskell allowing this magic, not just some GHC hack (like defaulting in GHCi)

Comment: @Eric As I understand it, yes. But _only_ for `Num` and `Eq` (AFAIR).

Comment: The keyword could be applied anywhere in theory though, right? It's not specific to `Num` and `Eq`?

Comment: The defaulting mechanism is specific to ``Num`` and all subclasses of ``Num``, ``Num`` has a special status in the type checker. There's also a mechanism for overloaded string literals thats very similar, but it's not on by default.