# Type defaulting with non-standard Prelude

Tags: haskell, ghc

The following program compiles with GHC:

```
main :: IO ()
main = print $ 2^2
```

despite the signature of

```
(^) :: (Num a, Integral b) => a -> b -> a
```

due to GHC's [type defaulting mechanism](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21943624/why-is-an-explicit-type-not-required-for-basic-prelude-arithmetic). I'm using [numeric-prelude](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/numeric-prelude), which instead exports

```
(^) :: Ring.C a => a -> Integer -> a
```

This is extremely annoying to use with `Int` exponents, so I prefer Prelude's version with a polymorphic exponent. Thus, I define the following:

```
{-# LANGUAGE NoImplicitPrelude, RebindableSyntax, ScopedTypeVariables #-}

import Algebra.Ring as Ring (C)
import Algebra.ToInteger as ToInteger (C)
import NumericPrelude hiding ((^))

(^) :: forall a i . (Ring.C a, ToInteger.C i) => a -> i -> a
x0 ^ y0 = undefined

main :: IO ()
main = print $ 2^2
```

but I get no type defaulting, so there are errors about ambiguous types for the base and exponent.

[This](https://wiki.haskell.org/Keywords#default) is the extent of documentation I could find about defaulting, which doesn't describe what the components of the tuple actually do, nor when the "default" default types are available.

Just from playing around, it looks like GHC is magically applying defaulting rules to built-in numeric types like `Num` and `Integral`, rather than to literals of arbitrary type.

Is there a way to extend this GHC magic to default any "integer-looking" type to (say) `Int`, even when the constraint is not `Integral a`? Adding an explicit `default (Int)` (assuming that's the right way to do it), doesn't help.

More specifically, the problem I'm trying to solve is to find a way to use one function `(^)` that works for

1. `Int` exponents
2. `Integer` exponents
3. literal exponents with no explicit type annotation

so any solution that achieves those three points would suffice.

Comment: Yeah, read [4.3.4](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch4.html#x10-750004.3). It look like `Num` really is magical. That seems like a restriction that ought to be loosened, although how I don't know.

Comment: Yep, `Num` **is** treated specially and there currently is no way to make custom defaulting work properly. You can only choose "built-in" types and even then it wont work for all classes.

Comment: https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/12271

Comment: I tend to define locally `(^) :: Num a => a -> Int -> a; (^) = Prelude.(^)`. For almost all applications, `Int` exponents are all that's sensible.